# JavaScript event loop during page unload

Tags: javascript, mobile-browser, onunload

I provide a 3rd party JavaScript code, which updates the server with messages relating to events happening on the web page. The messages are queued until I reach a certain buffer size, and than flushed from the queue and sent through AJAX calls. When I detect a page unload I flush the remaining messages in the queue.

My problem is that sometimes the server doesn't receive the last batch of messages which was queued on the client. This problem is definitely more common on mobile browsers, seems more common on Safari than on Chrome (not certain), this happens more frequently when unload is a result of a form submit.

My guess is that at some arbitrary point the browser stops JavaScript execution regardless of pending queued events, and/or disregarding an executing stack. Since the messages are sent asynchronously, I assume that the sending stack was either never called, or stopped before the AJAX call was reached.

This problem seems to be impersistent even when tested on the same machine and web application, which implies that the momentary processor load plays a role.

My questions are:

1. When is JavaScript execution stopped by browsers during unload?
2. Is an executing stack guaranteed to run till completion during unload?
3. If the browser indeed cuts execution arbitrarily, is there any way
   to postpone it?
4. Are there any other means to insure all queued events get executed before the page is unloaded?
5. Is there any way to query the status of the event queue?

Comment: Ultimately there are no guarantees. A user might pull the plug out of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

to your questions:

1) at any time

2) no.

3) no, not at all.

4) not at this moment, must be done before and must be finished befor unload occurs.

5) what event queue?

Comment: I'm referring to the queue which holds the callbacks waiting for execution. Thanks Axel.

Comment: You might catch the `onunload` event and ask the user whether he wants to leave the page and cancel that on behalf of the user. But the event doesn't occur in all possible cases and if the user hits yes, the scripts get interrupted anyway.